# Securing a local Java embedded database

Tags: java, security, encryption, h2

I am a member of a sports association and I am developping a simple JavaFX application for managing member's license.

This application will be used on a notebook without any connection, it has to be offline an protected by a user/password. It will run on a shared Windows account.

The application must be the simpliest possible to install and use (average user age around 60-70 years old) so for storing data I plan to use an embedded Java database (I started with H2 in db file mode but I can switch to another engine) with some user restriction.

Everything work so far and users only have access to the desired informations but my problem is that everyone who can access the notebook can freely open the DB file with notepad or something else and see all confidential informations.

I known that H2 offer some database encryption and I test with AES and it work so far, but I don't known of to deal with the DB password.

The DB must have a single password but I want the application so be accesible and started by any user without the help of an administrator (who would enter the master password for example)

How can I secure the information in the database and make it usable by multiple users (one at a time) without an administrator involved for master password?

Comment: Note that H2 offers both, either client/server (you can do both) or embedded single-user database. The latter is not multi-user, and would need some lock (like a lock file).

Comment: Perhaps my question is unclear. I need multiple users but only one at the same time. Tha application is offline and only one person use the computer at a time but multiple users should be able to start it (and decrypt it)

Comment: Should every user be able to decrypt the whole database?

Comment: If possible there should be 2 level of access (basic informations and full informations) but it's acceptable if every user can decrypt the whole database